# Why is strangeness enhanced in quark-gluon plasma?

Tags: nuclear-physics, quark-gluon-plasma

How does the observation of strangeness enhancement in high-multiplicity proton–proton collisions explain the existence of quark-gluon plasma?

Comment: Did you mean to ask about the phenomenon of strangeness enhancement in heavy-ion collisions in general? Or are you specifically asking about the interpretation of the effect in proton-proton collisions?

Comment: Sorry for not being precise, what I hoped was to get a "simple" answer explaining strangeness enhancement as a signature for QGP

Comment: Wikipedia article on this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangeness_and_quark%E2%80%93gluon_plasma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In complement to answer 1 we should also remember that in QGP the threshold of strangeness production is lower compared to confined phase. Moreover, the color degeneracy factor 3 helps to enhance the yield above confined phase. In relativistic heavy ion collisions we see strong evidence for QGP based on observed pattern of strangeness production as function of collision energy and centrality of collision.

Answer (score 3):

The temperature of the quark-gluon plasma (above $150$ MeV) is significantly higher than the mass of the strange quark (which is $101$ MeV). This means that it's hot enough that "extra" strange quarks can be produced via thermal fluctuations in the medium (i.e. the energy density in a particular pocket of QGP gets randomly high enough that a $s\bar{s}$ pair forms). Without QGP, strange quarks can only come from either hard scatterings or heavy-quark decays, so there are fewer of them.